# What counts towards the GAE datastore quotas?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

The docs say that there are 50,000 free Read, Write, and Small Operations to the datastore.

I guess read and write are obvious, but what falls under the "small ops" category? If I ran a query would it be a small or read operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Cost) on this. As I understand it, queries by key are considered "small operations," so a query for entities, a query for keys, and creating a new key all deplete the small operations quota.

A query is both a small and read operation: it costs 1 read + 1 small per entity retrieved.

Comment: Ah, interesting. So there's no cost advantage to using a keys-only query?

Comment: That doesn't seem right, does it? It seems like keys-only should be cheaper. Here's another [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923584/how-much-quota-does-an-appengine-datastore-query-cost) about this. I'll run two queries and look at the logs like it suggests.